# why I cannot control mouse in the new VM when use VMWare

Tags: vmware-workstation

I'm trying to install an old version of Mas OS 10.8, I downloaded the iso file then create a new VM. But I cannot control the mouse in the installation process, what's going on?

Comment: Could you clarify which version of VMWare you are running. Your tag says VMWare Workstation, but that is not authorised to run macOS, so you will have no hardware drivers. You need VMWare Fusion. Also macOS is not supplied on an ISO, so I suspect you are installing an unofficial copy, which would make this question off-topic.

Answer (score 0):

1)  I would verify it's not a mouse problem by first testing the mouse on another computer.

2)  Then post the results, and clarify "cannot control the mouse", such as "my mouse cursor will not move", or "mouse pointer is not visible".

3)  When you post that you will have eliminated mouse malfunction, and narrowed down the suspects to either computer or software malfunction.

4) I suggest you check out the answers on this similar VMware/mouse problem post:   [Windows 8.1 in a VMWare Workstation 10 guest's mouse is missing, but only sometimes](https://superuser.com/questions/706121/windows-8-1-in-a-vmware-workstation-10-guests-mouse-is-missing-but-only-someti?rq=1)

The 1st three should help a VMware expert to easier diagnose your problem - the last one might actually help solve your problem. Sorry I can't help more.

Answer (score 0):

When using VMWare workstation, use Ctrl + Alt keys for enabling mouse input in virtual drive.